# How to localize something coming from theme customizer

Tags: theme-customizer, localization

```
<p><?php echo get_theme_mod('simplisto_p'); ?></p>
```

something is saved in the database through a theme customizer and then pulled through `get_theme_mod`.

## My Question →

How to localize this?
`_e` something of this sort to be used. I can use this on normal strings but confused how to do this here.

Comment: If it's a text field, why would you? The user can put in whatever they want in their own language. If it's some sort of select then you just localize the options.

Comment: Actually, you are right to an extent, but we live in an era of a multilingual website. Suppose the primary website is in English, but the webmaster wants all pages/posts to be in Spanish also than localization plays a role. Various plugins such as wpml also require localized coding so that they can instantanize the cloning of pages but in different language.

Comment: You're [not supposed to](http://ottopress.com/2012/internationalization-youre-probably-doing-it-wrong/) put variables or code inside __() functions because that's not how translations work. WPML has its [own way](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/translating-theme-options/) of translating theme options that doesn't involve __() functions for this reason.

Comment: what should I do close the question? or you will write an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a text field, why would you? The user can put in whatever they want in their own language. If it's some sort of select then you just localize the options.

Regardless, [you're not supposed to](http://ottopress.com/2012/internationalization-youre-probably-doing-it-wrong/) put variables or code inside `__()` functions because that's not how translations work. WPML has [its own way](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/translating-theme-options/) of translating theme options that doesn't involve `__()` functions for this reason.